# Is there some place on the internet where I can run my Java program?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

A program I am working on takes forever to complete (~3days, everytime).

Is there some place on the internet where I can leave the code, some robot might run it for me and I can come back and collect the results? Some online judge that offers this capability?

[I am not talking abt optimisations here.]

Comment: What exactly are you doing that is taking 3 days to complete?  Maybe if you gave more information about what type of application this is, and what you are trying to achieve, we can give some tailored respones.

Comment: While you are not talking about optimization in this question, you should certainly be thinking about it.  3 days is a really long time for a computation to take.  Something that takes that long needs to be properly profiled to find where most of the time is spent.

Answer (score 7):

You may need to go to something like this:

> Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon
>   EC2) is a web service that provides
>   resizable compute capacity in the
>   cloud. It is designed to make
>   web-scale computing easier for
>   developers.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Answer (score 4):

If you really cannot run it on your own machines, you can run in on [Amazon EC2 cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).  You would need to maintain a virtual machine, but Amazon provides some preconfigured settings.

The pricing starts with $0.085/hour (~$6 for three days).  The actual price is determined by the duration of use and your CPU needs.  Higher CPU capability is more expensive.

Comment: It sounds like hanifr's app is CPU-bound, and could probably run faster and ultimately cheaper on a "High-CPU" instance.